# why I cannot multiple parameter in golang what wrong with my sql query?

Tags: sql, database, go

I have problem with  multiple parameter , I cannot implementing 2 parameter with sql query. and I'm still get error , error display mssql: Incorrect syntax near 'SequenceID'. what wrong with my query sql or maybe I wrong with my code ?

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main()  {
    db, err :=  sql.Open("sqlserver","sqlserver://sa:@localhost:1433?database=CONFINS&connection+timeout=30")
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
    }


err = db.Ping()

if err != nil {
    fmt.Print(err.Error())
}
defer db.Close()

type SMSBlast struct {
    SequenceID  int
    MobilePhone string
    Output  string
    WillBeSentDate *time.Time
    SentDate *time.Time
    Status *string
    DtmUpd *time.Time
}

router := gin.Default()

//Get a SMSBlast  detail
router.POST("/SMSBlast/:SequenceID", func(context *gin.Context) {
    var(
        smsblast SMSBlast
        result gin.H
    )

SequenceID := context.Param("SequenceID")
MobilePhone := context.Param("MobilePhone")

    err := db.QueryRow("select SequenceID, MobilePhone, Output, WillBeSentDate, SentDate, Status, DtmUpd from SMSblast2 where SequenceID  IS NOT NULL  AND MobilePhone IS NOT NULL  "+SequenceID , MobilePhone).Scan(&smsblast.SequenceID, &smsblast.MobilePhone, &smsblast.Output, &smsblast.WillBeSentDate, &smsblast.SentDate, &smsblast.Status, &smsblast.DtmUpd)
    //fmt.Println(row)
    fmt.Println(err)
    //err = row.Scan(&smsblast.SequenceID, &smsblast.MobilePhone, &smsblast.Output, &smsblast.WillBeSentDate, &smsblast.SentDate, &smsblast.Status, &smsblast.DtmUpd)
    if err != nil{
        //if no results send null
        result = gin.H{
            "result": nil,
            "count":  0,
        }
        }else{
            result = gin.H{
                "result" : smsblast,
                "count" : 1,
            }
        }

    context.JSON(http.StatusOK, result)
})
```

Comment: 1. **NEVER** build up your query by concatenating strings. 2. Test the query first. 3. Read the documentation of `QueryRow` and think about what MobilePhone is doing in there. 4. Ask a human (this is more efficient).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Since your query doesn't contain any placeholders (`?` chars), there should be no additional args to `QueryRow`. Perhaps remove the extra args:

```
db.QueryRow("select SequenceID, MobilePhone, Output, WillBeSentDate, SentDate, Status, DtmUpd from SMSblast2 where SequenceID  IS NOT NULL AND MobilePhone IS NOT NULL").Scan[...]
```

Comment: I try with ? , but still get error "mssql: Incorrect syntax near '?'."